Movie where the only survivor from a space colony or expedition is found and recovered by a ship. He turns out to be infected and turns evil
I am thinking that I have seen this in the 1990's or 80's but am not sure. I did not see the complete movie and don't know how it ended or began.
When I started watching it, they recovered a guy that was in some kind of escape pod. The crew wondered how he managed to survive. The medic of the crew, a female, examined the man nude and did some tests. It was implied that during the examination he got an erection. He apologized for it. She says "well you certainly are surprisingly fit and healthy" or something similar.
Anyways, it's determined that he is exceptionally above average in strength and inelegance. But he keeps getting more superhuman strength and intelligence, and mad with power. Turns out he had some kind of alien infection that caused this and must be how the others died. A battle for control of the ship starts because of his superiority complex.
Any help in identifying this movie would be great. I don't remember it that well, so details may be off. Thanks.

Hi. Do you recall anything distinctive about any of the characters in terms of appearance, age, ethnicity, etc?

Reminiscent of Space Seed, with  Khan Noonien Singh's first appearance in Star Trek, but there were multiple rescuees that time.

By the way, did you mean to say "strength and intelligence" rather than "strength and inelegance"...?

Might it be Event Horizon?

@JiminyCricket. Not that either episode is the answer that OldTC seeks, but IMO, the ToS second pilot, "Where no Man Has Gone Before," would be the closer match. In that episode, the Enterprise is sent to learn the fate of a lost starship. At the very edge of known space (i.e., where no man has gone before,) they find evidence that the captain intentionally sacrificed his ship and crew to prevent some unknown catastrophe. Then, two of the Enterprise crew members start to develop god-like powers and, god-like attitudes...

Is this Supernova (2000)...?

A deep space rescue and recovery spaceship with a crew of 6 receives a distress call from a mining operation 3432 light years away. A rescue operation via dimension jump is made. Bad idea.

After receiving an emergency distress signal, the crew of a medical ship travel to a mining operation on a distant moon and rescue a young man. He has a mysterious, glowing alien artefact with him. He's subjected to medical scans while nude and judged to be "healthy as a horse."
Shortly after that, there's a scene where he walks up to a female member of the crew while still nude and initiates small talk with her. I'm not certain if he's supposed to have an erection in this scene or not, but he does mention that he's embarrassed and that he hasn't been around a girl in a while, which can certainly be taken as implying that he did. And either way, it was clearly an awkward and uncomfortable interaction for the female crew member.
I don't want to spoil any more than I need to to answer this question, but the man does grow stronger and and more maniacal as the movie progresses, leading to confrontations with other crew members.




Interesting to note that this film had some well-known actors and the involvement of at least two geniuses (FFC and Hill) but it ended up bombing like crazy. Too bad. Science fiction can be very good, even great; but I think of all genres, scifi has the greatest chance, if history is any guide, of failure. (MST3K is built on this, scifi and horror.)

@releseabe it also had a great FTL special effect
